# Command Line error stored in a file

Tags: python, subprocess, particles

I am firing a SPH simulation using a Dual SPH executables. It has four consecutive subprocess commands that progresses to produce the vtk files of the simulation. The problem is that assuming particle distance in SPH is very sensitive and there is no proper way to calculate it. If the particle distance is too high then it will fail to run the first command and it will give an error. I want to write a code which could read the error given by the first subprocess so that i can optimize over particle distance. Is there any way I can read the error given by the first subprocess?

```
Gen = subprocess.Popen(args = sph_location+"\\"+"GenCase4_win64"+" "+def_out+" "+out+"\\"+r"z -save:all", shell='TRUE')
Gen.communicate()
Dual = subprocess.Popen(args= sph_location+"\\"+"DualSPHysics4.2_win64"+" "+out+"\\"+r"z -svres -cpu", shell='TRUE')
Dual.communicate()
Vtk = subrocess.Popen(args= sphlocation+"\\"+"PartVTK4_win64"+" -savevtk "+out+"\\"+r"zPartFluid -onlytype:-all,+fluid -vars:+vol", shell='TRUE')
Surface = subprocess.Popen(args= sph_location+"\\"+"IsoSurface4_win64"+" "+r"-onlytype:+fluid -vars:+vol -saveiso surface" ,shell='TRUE') 
Surface.communicate()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html?#subprocess.Popen.communicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Gen = subprocess.Popen(args = sph_location+"\\"+"GenCase4_win64"+" "+def_out+" "+out+"\\"+r"z -save:all", shell='TRUE', stderr=subprocess.PIPE)    
output,error = Gen.communicate()
print(error)
```

This will wait for command to finish and give you output or error depending on the state of command.

Comment: Thats the thing, on doing that it shows error None but there was an exception raised in that code. I want to read that exception in the code

Comment: @SwagatamSengupta add stderr=subprocess.PIPE to your Popen

Comment: Hey @Nuts this doesn't even show the exception message

Comment: This is the Exception i want to read
 *** Exception (JPartsLoad4::CalculateCasePos)
Text: The limits of the initial case cannot be calculated from a file PART.

Comment: @SwagatamSengupta error message is being printed. Try to check if you get the error: `if error: raise ValueError(error)`

Comment: Hey @Nuts. I can't understand. Do you want me to raise an exception with argument as  *** Exception (JPartsLoad4::CalculateCasePos) Text: The limits of the initial case cannot be calculated from a file PART ?

Comment: output,error = Gen.communicate() - will not show error message in the console. But it should return error message in the error variable(if process finished with exit code !=0)